# admin_notices on runtime in function

Tags: actions

I have a function that is called at a post updated, inside of this function I am doing something and if this went wrong I want to display an `admin_notices`.

**Inside** of my **function** I tried the following:

```
if($error) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
}
```

`my_admin_notice` looks like:

```
function my_admin_notice() {
    ?>
        <div class="error">
            <p>Error happend</p>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

If I call `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );` outside of my function it's working, but unfortunately the notice is display always... :/

**Update - Context details:**

My function is called with `add_filter ( 'publish_post', 'my_function' );`

Inside of this function I check if the post is published the first time, than I am doing some stuff and if there is something wrong I want to call the `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );` to display an error message...

My function is working well and is only getting called if I want, so that's not the problem...

What I think is that the `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );` that I call inside of my function is getting ignored!

**Update Code for Context:**

```
function my_admin_notice() {
    ?>
        <div class="error">
            <p>Error happend</p>
        </div>
    <?php
}

function checkEdit()  {

    if( ($_POST['post_type'] == 'post') && ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) &&
     ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {

    $title =  get_the_title();

    $postId = (string) get_the_ID();

    $postUrl = get_site_url() . "?p=" . $postId;
    $wp_category_array = get_the_category(); 


    $categoryArray = array();
    foreach ($wp_category_array as $wp_category => $value) {
        $categoryArray[] = $value->cat_ID;
    }

    $postDate = get_the_date('Y-m-j H:i:s');
    $subTitle = get_the_date();

    $parse = new parseRestClient(array(
        'appid' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'restkey' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    ));

    $params = array(
        'className' => 'News',
        'object' => array(
            'Title' => $title,
            'SubTitle' => $subTitle,
            'array' => $categoryArray,
            'code' => $postId,
            'Date' => $postDate,
            'Url' => $postUrl
        )
    );

    $request = $parse->create($params);

    $responseArray = json_decode($request, true);

    $objectId = $responseArray['objectId'];

    if ($responseArray ['error'] == true) {
        // Called if error (working)
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
    }else {
        $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET parseId = '$objectId' WHERE ID = '$postId'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    }
}

add_action ( 'post_updated', 'checkEdit');
```

Comment: Can you post your code in context?

Comment: @s_ha_dum it's about a little wordpress plugin i road, which is doing some stuff after a post is published...
I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Telling me what the code is "about" doesn't put it the code in context. I still have no idea how it is used.

Comment: @s_ha_dum okay sorry I try it again, the plugin is used to send data to a REST-Api and if the REST-Api return an error I want to display a error message for the user.
In the function I am doing a php curl which returns succes or error.
If error is returned i want to show the admin notice to the user. Hope this infos helps you :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but what would help would be actual working (truncated if necessary) code that I read as a whole, and copy and paste into a dev stack if necessary. Are you attempting to apply an action inside an AJAX request and have it honored on the non-AJAX part of the site?

Comment: @s_ha_dum okay I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

I saw this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19822056), may be able to modify it to work in your situation:

```
function my_function($post_id){

    if($error){
           set_transient( get_current_user_id().'publisherror', "Error Message" );
    }
    return $post_id;
}
add_filter ( 'publish_post', 'my_function' );

function show_admin_notice() {
    if($out = get_transient( get_current_user_id().'publisherror' ) ) {
        delete_transient( get_current_user_id().'publisherror' );
        echo '<div class="error"><p>'.$out.'</p></div>';
    }

}
add_action('admin_notices', "show_admin_notice");
```